# connect google cloud storage to mysql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud

Hi I am not sure If I am heading towards a right solution and needed some advice.

I have some social media platform connectors that dump files in a CSV format. What I am trying to achieve is for instance a CSV file has impressions, reach, clicks as columns - I want to then create a data pipeline in Google Cloud Platform to use MySQL workbench to input only impressions and clicks from the CSV files into a table.

is this possible? If not, what are the recommendations? I can use Big Query for this but we just want to work with a subset of the CSV data and not all of it.

Suggestions please!

Comment: Which part of your process do you want to achieve in GCP? Where's the data initially stored? Do you need any data processing?

Answer (score 0):

For you there is [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep) - An intelligent cloud data service to visually explore, clean, and prepare data.

There you can

- feed in all your CSV from Cloud Storage
- visually explore
- setup recipes to cleaning, transforming
- or filtering, or joining datasets
- and jobs to write the combined results into a final CSV for example or BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

According to the power and the price of BigQuery, I will use it. You can either load your file in BigQuery in staging/temp tables or let them in Cloud Storage and scan them with [federated table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage)

The principle is to query the files, get the columns/data that you want, optionally transform/filter/clean them, and store them in your final table

```
Create table XXX
Select ... from <Staging table/external table>
```